# How to set icons without gap?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout, border-layout

I'm using java swing. I want to add grid of pictures.

```
public class LayoutTest {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridLayout demo");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton btn1 = new JButton("First");
    JButton btn2 = new JButton("Second");
    JButton btn3 = new JButton("Third");
    JButton btn4 = new JButton("Fourth");
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JButton btn12 = new JButton("First2");
    JButton btn22 = new JButton("Second2");
    JButton btn32 = new JButton("Third2");
    JButton btn42 = new JButton("Fourth2");
    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
    JButton btn13 = new JButton("First2");
    JButton btn23 = new JButton("Second2");
    JButton btn33 = new JButton("Third2");
    JButton btn43 = new JButton("Fourth2");

    JLabel label13 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("pictures/building.jpg"), JLabel.CENTER);
    JLabel label23 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("pictures/building2.png"), JLabel.CENTER);
    JLabel label33 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("pictures/building.jpg"), JLabel.CENTER);
    JLabel label43 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("pictures/building2.png"), JLabel.CENTER);
    public LayoutTest() {
        panel3.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,0,0));
        panel3.add(label13);
        panel3.add(label23);
        panel3.add(label33);
        panel3.add(label43);

        frame.add(panel3);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
//        frame.setSize(40,40);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

As a result I get this: [image: this image]. I'm using gridLayout. My pictures are 20x20 pixels size. How can I add images without this horizontal gap?

Comment: It appears that the frame decorations are forcing the extra size. If the four icons were added in a single row, the gap should decrease or disappear. General tips: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). ..

Comment: .. 3) Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: To expand on my first comment. The default layout for a frame is `BorderLayout`. When a component is added to a border layout without constraint being specified, it will end up in the `CENTER`. The component (`panel3`) added to the center of a border layout will be stretched to fill the entire width and height available. A `GridLayout` will assign an equal width and height as needed for the widest and tallest grid cell. So the behaviour could also be avoided by adding `panel3` to either the `LINE_START` or `LINE_END` of the content pane - these positions will stretch height but respect width,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, Andrew Thompson! Seems like using bigger size of grid works well!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the frame decorations are forcing the extra size. If the four icons were added in a single row, the gap should decrease or disappear.

The default layout for a frame is `BorderLayout`. When a component is added to a border layout without constraint being specified, it will end up in the `CENTER`. The component (`panel3`) added to the center of a border layout will be stretched to fill the entire width and height available. A `GridLayout` will assign an equal width and height as needed for the widest and tallest grid cell. So the behaviour could also be avoided by adding `panel3` to either the `LINE_START` or `LINE_END` of the content pane - these positions will stretch height but respect width.

Here is an example which demonstrates the effect within each constraint of a border layout.

[image] [image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class GridLayoutSpace {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    GridLayoutSpace() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));

        addFourIcons(Color.ORANGE, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        addFourIcons(Color.ORANGE, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        addFourIcons(Color.BLUE, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        addFourIcons(Color.BLUE, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        addFourIcons(Color.YELLOW, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private void addFourIcons(Color bg, String constraint) {
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2, 0, 0));
        p.setBackground(bg);
        ui.add(p, constraint);
        p.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getImage(Color.RED))));
        p.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getImage(Color.GREEN))));
        p.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getImage(Color.GREEN))));
        p.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getImage(Color.RED))));
    }
    int sz = 24;
    private BufferedImage getImage(Color color) {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(sz, sz, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(0,0, sz, sz);
        g.dispose();
        return bi;
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                GridLayoutSpace o = new GridLayoutSpace();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```